# Yii2 print the column name and its value using loop

Tags: mysql, yii2

I'm trying to print the column name and it's value of a table using foreach loop of each column in my table. I want this code

```
$contentAfter = DepCustomer::findOne($id);
echo $contentAfter->customer_id;
echo $contentAfter->account_no;
echo $contentAfter->name;
echo $contentAfter->address;
echo $contentAfter->gender;
```

to be executed in this way

```
$contentAfter = DepCustomer::findOne($id);
foreach($contentAfter as $name => $value){
   echo $name .': '. $value;
}
```

I have tried using asArray() also but I'm getting error.

Comment: The second code block is correct. What error do you see?

Comment: Which error u r getting?

Comment: Thank you all. I've solved my problem. Earlier I was getting 'calling unknown method'. maybe I overlook something. Again I wrote my code as given above. Now it's working. Once again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use asArray for obtain an Array and not an object. 
Furthermore the foreach code should be encolsed in {} and the echo should be on all the column

```
  $contentAfter = DepCustomer::find->where(['id'=> $id])->asArray()->one();
  foreach($contentAfter as $name => $value) {

    echo $name .':' . $value->customer_id . '<br />';
    echo $name .':' . $value->account_no . '<br />';
    echo $name .':' . $value->name . '<br />';
    echo $name .':' . $value->address . '<br />';
    echo $name .':' . $value->gender . '<br />';

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is not what I' m trying to achieved. i think my question is somewhat ambigous. Sorry for that. I want to print the column name and its value using a loop instead of printing each and every column.

Comment: @gojiraki   . i have update the answer hope is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

do you want to print in screen? maybe you can try this.
if you want to print single row of object DepCustomer, you can use print_r

```
$contentAfter = DepCustomer::findOne($id);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($contentAfter);
echo '</pre>';
```

if yout want to print multiple rows of object, you can use foreach and print_r

```
$contentAfter = DepCustomer::find()->where()->all();
foreach($contentAfter as $v){
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($v);
  echo '</pre>';
  echo '<br/>';
}
```

i hope it help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've solved my problem. earlier I was getting 'calling unknown method'. maybe I overlook something. Again I wrote my code as given above. Now it's working